# Prevent conditional formatting on entire sheet

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

I've got this VBA code which applies conditional formatting pairwise across my sheet. By that I mean, it looks for duplicates from BC, DE, FG, ect. The problem is that it does this for the entire column and it's really slowing down my sheet

When I check the rules generated by this code for say, column B and D, it is applied to: =$B$1:$C$87,$B$89:$C$1048576. The reason this skips ROW 88 is because I have totals at this row and removed all rules. Is there a way to alter this code so it only applies to rows 87 and up and not the entire sheet? Right now it's slowing things down considerably.

```
Sub findDups()
Dim startCell As Range
Dim formatCols As Range

Set startCell = ActiveCell

Do
    Set formatCols = startCell.Resize(1, 2).EntireColumn

    formatCols.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
    formatCols.FormatConditions(formatCols.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    formatCols.FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
    With formatCols.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16383844
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With formatCols.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13551615
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

    Set startCell = startCell.Offset(0, 2)

Loop Until startCell.Column >= 26

End Sub
```

Comment: which cell is your activecell when you start your sub?

Comment: Dollars to donuts it is not the conditional formatting slowing things down, but the screen-updating. Try setting `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` while your VBA code runs, and setting it true again once it completes.

Comment: The slow down occurs after the vba above has completed running.  But once and item is entered, it checks for duplicates through the entire column for two columns.  That's over 2 million cells when only 160 max need to be checked.  I think it's the conditional formatting rules causing the lag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the `formatCols`
(that's strange, I can't see anything in your code that avoids line 88)

```
...
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set startCell = ActiveSheet.Range("B1")

Do
    Set formatCols = startCell.Worksheet.Range(startCell, startCell.Offset(86, 1))

    ...
Loop Until ....

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
.....
```

Comment: Sorry. I actually went in and highlighted that row and removed all conditional formatting applied to it.  Otherwise this code runs on the entire sheet.

Comment: I see...anyway, this code I've posted does the job for the first 87 lines (where you read `...` use your original code)

Answer (score 0):

One way I use to limit the ranges selected is to find the last cell in a column.
Where you're using this code:

```
Set formatCols = startCell.Resize(1, 2).EntireColumn
```

I would change it to use a Range object:

1. Declare a new Range object and set it to the column you wish to format
2. Find the last value in that column (if it's 87, this can be used, otherwise you can use startCell.End(xlDown)
3. Set the new Range variable to use the range up to this cell
4. Use the Range value to apply the formatting to

This should speed up your code.

You can also try a few extra things:

1. Set Application.ScreenUpdating to False
2. Set Application.Calculation to xlCalculationManual

Hope it helps!

CompleteITPro